# R stats on data from multiple rows and columns by name

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a large dataframe with 12 rows corresponding to each unique ID.  I want to calculate the mean for values from 8 columns by ID.  In other words, I want single value means for all values in a 12x8 block (some have many NAs)

Here's a simpler version with 3x4 blocks:

```
ht.1<-c(3,2,4,4,5,4)
ht.2<-c(3,7,3,4,1,2)
ht.3<-c(5,4,3,6,3,NA)
ht.4<-c(6,2,3,3,NA,4)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),ht.1=ht.1,ht.2=ht.2,ht.3=ht.3,ht.4=ht.4)
```

I'm looking for the mean of all values that correspond with "A" and "B"

Aggregate function?

Hope that makes sense--I'm new to this site and R.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `unlist` the relevant values and then aggregate the values. Here's an approach in base R:

```
by(DF[-1], DF[1], FUN = function(x) mean(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE))
# ID: A
# [1] 3.75
# ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# ID: B
# [1] 3.6
```

Alternatively, you can use `stack` and then `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(values ~ ID, cbind(DF[1], stack(DF[-1])), 
          function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
#   ID values
# 1  A   3.75
# 2  B   3.60
```

---

The "data.table" approach is particularly compact and efficient:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(DF)[, mean(unlist(.SD), na.rm = TRUE), by = ID]
#    ID   V1
# 1:  A 3.75
# 2:  B 3.60
```

---

And here are two takes from the Hadleyverse.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(DF, id.vars = "ID"), ID ~ "mean.ht", value.var = "value", 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
#   ID mean.ht
# 1  A    3.75
# 2  B    3.60

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  gather(var, val, ht.1:ht.4) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(val = mean(val, na.rm = TRUE))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
# 
#   ID  val
# 1  A 3.75
# 2  B 3.60
```

Comment: Thanks, Ananda.  I appreciate the different options.

Answer (score 0):

One option in `base R` is

```
 vapply(split(DF[-1], DF$ID), function(x) mean(as.matrix(x), 
             na.rm=TRUE), numeric(1L))
 #   A    B 
 #3.75 3.60
```

Or

```
 tapply(as.matrix(DF[-1]), DF$ID[row(DF[-1])], FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
 #  A   B 
 #3.75 3.60
```

Or

```
 library(dplyr)
  DF %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     do(data.frame(val=mean(unlist(.[-1]), na.rm=TRUE)))
  #  ID  val
  #1  A 3.75
  #2  B 3.60
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun, but I guess I wasn't clear about my goal.  I want the mean of ALL values for A and B, not a mean for each column.  What I ultimately want is:  A  3.75    B  3.6.   Of course, I want to be able to do it for many unique IDs with larger matrices of values than in my simplified example.

Comment: @erictall The best way to clarify your goal is to provide your expected output (as an R object) as part of the question.